# API restful @mantytoone JPA, Spring boot - 404 not found

Tags: java-ee, spring-boot, jpa

La api rest de estas dos entidades la estoy testeando en un postman que me da 404, eclipse compila bien el proyecto, asi que supongo que es algo mal planteado en la logica de mi service o controlador, no se en cual de los estoy estoy mal o si en ambas clases.

Abajo dejo las tablas una institucion tiene muchos institutos

```
@Entity(name="Instituto")
@Table(name="instituto")
public class InstitutoEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_INSTITUCION", nullable = false)
    private InstitucionEntity institucion;

    @Column (name = "NOMBRE", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String nombre;

    @Column (name = "COLOR_HEXA", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String color_hexa;


    public InstitutoEntity() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public InstitutoEntity(int id, InstitucionEntity institucion, String nombre, String color_hexa) {
        this.id = id;
        this.institucion = institucion;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.color_hexa = color_hexa;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public InstitucionEntity getInstitucion() {
        return institucion;
    }


    public void setInstitucion(InstitucionEntity institucion) {
        this.institucion = institucion;
    }


    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }


    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }


    public String getColor_hexa() {
        return color_hexa;
    }


    public void setColor_hexa(String color_hexa) {
        this.color_hexa = color_hexa;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "InstitutoEntity {"+ 
                "id=" + id + ","
                + " institucion=" + institucion + ", "
                + "nombre=" + nombre + ", "
                + "color_hexa="+ color_hexa + "}";
    }    

}
```

>

```
    @Entity (name = "Institucion")
    @Table (name = "institucion_educativa")
    public class InstitucionEntity {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column (name = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
        private int id;

        @Column (name = "NOMBRE", length = 30, nullable = false)
        private String nombre;

        public InstitucionEntity () {
            super();
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }

        public void setNombre(String nombre) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }


    }






public interface InstitutoRepository extends JpaRepository<InstitutoEntity, Integer>{
    InstitutoEntity getInstitutoById(int id);
    List<InstitutoEntity> getAllInstituto();

}
```

`

```
@Service
public class InstitutoService  {

    @Autowired
    InstitutoRepository institutoRepository; 


    public List<InstitutoEntity> getAllInstituto() {
        return institutoRepository.findAll();

    }


    public Optional<InstitutoEntity> getInstitutoById(int id) {
        return institutoRepository.findById(id);
    }



@RestController
public class InstitutoController {

  @Autowired
  private InstitutoService institutoService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/institutos", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public List<InstitutoEntity> getInstitutos() {
        return institutoService.getAllInstituto();
    }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/instituto/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public Optional<InstitutoEntity> getInstituto(@PathVariable("id")int id) {
        return institutoService.getInstitutoById(id);
    }

}
```

properties

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
server.servlet.context-path = /api
server.port = 8080
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true


# Logger configurations.
logging.level.com.capgemini.serviciosya = DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.data  = DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type = TRACE


# Hibernate
hibernate.dialect  = org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate
entitymanager.packagesToScan = ar.edu.unaj.reports.entity

spring.profiles.active=dev
```

[image: tablas]

Comment: Un 404 es No encontrado, en principio tiene que ver con la definición de los endpoints de la api que no están en el código que incluiste. Tenes que empezar a mirar por donde tengas el `@RestController` y los `@RequestMapping` por ejemplo.

Comment: ahí agregue el controller, sigo sin poder solucionarlo :(

Comment: 2018-11-18 16:43:21.199 DEBUG 13164 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Looking up handler method for path /instituto
2018-11-18 16:43:21.204 DEBUG 13164 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Did not find handler method for [/instituto]
2018-11-18 16:43:21.204 DEBUG 13164 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Looking up handler method for path /instituto
2018-11-18 16:43:21.207 DEBUG 13164 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Did not find handler method for [/instituto]

Comment: le pasaste un id al instituto? /instituto/1 por ejemplo?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/api/instituto/1 me da   {
    "timestamp": "2018-11-18T19:52:14.300+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/api/instituto/1"
}

Comment: En las properties ahí agregue el archivo

Comment: Revisa el endpoint que definistes. Ve si la sentencia sql se esta ejecutando correctamente o te esta devolviendo un null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que `server.servlet.context-path = /api` solo funciona si el packing es war y no jar "configuración del pom.xml".
Si quieres que el root path sea "/api" hay que agregar un @RequestMapping a nivel de clase:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class InstitutoController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/institutos", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public List<InstitutoEntity> getInstitutos() {
        ...
    }

}
```

al inicializar spring en consola veras con log de las rutas mapeadas, te puede ser muy útil cuando hay problemas de rutas:

```
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api],methods=[GET]}" onto public ......
```

Comment: Gracias Mariano,marco tu respuesta como correcta así queda la solución :) Saludos.